# Using calculated results of select statement to calculate another column in single statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have an SQL statement like this :

```
Insert into @Matches(RowId, PercentMatch) select distinct t.[Row],
cast(Max(Counts) as float)/(Abs(Max(Counts) - case when Max(VarLength) >= @tempint then Max(VarLength) else @tempint end) + Max(Counts))* 100 
As MatchingPercent from @Temp t Group by [Row] order by MatchingPercent desc
```

Next sql statement that I have is :

```
Update @Matches set Percentage =  PercentMatch * @constantVal
```

I would like to highlight that `PercentMatch` column is "calculated" in above Insert into select statement.

**What I want to do :** How I may merge it in one statement ?

**Why I need this :**

It is inside of a procedure that is executed by 20-30 stored procedures that are executed in asynch (using Service broker).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place your `SELECT` in a subquery and insert `Percentage` value in the `INSERT` statement by performing the multiplication in an outer query:

```
Insert into @Matches(RowId, PercentMatch, Percentage) 
select tRow, MatchingPercent, MatchingPercent * @constantVal
from (
   select distinct t.[Row] as tRow, 
         cast(Max(Counts) as float) / (Abs(Max(Counts) 
         - 
         case 
           when Max(VarLength) >= @tempint then Max(VarLength) 
           else @tempint 
         end) + Max(Counts))* 100 As MatchingPercent 
from @Temp t 
Group by [Row] ) s
```

I also think `order by` clause is not of much use in a `INSERT INTO SELECT` statement.

Comment: and the distinct is useless too since theres already a group by in place